# Is my textbook implying that you can add matrices of different sizes?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

In the definition of addition of matrices, it states that you can only add matrices if they are the same size, but the example they gave showing this process is called: "Example 2.6: Addition of Matrices of Same Size"

Are they implying that you can eventually add matrices of other sizes or am I just overthinking the title?

Below is a picture of the example and definition for clarity.

Comment: Two matrices must have an equal number of rows and columns to be added

Comment: No, your textbook is not implying that you can add matrices of different sizes.

Comment: Note that some programming languages allow you to slightly redefine the addition. For example, in python/numpy you can add a scalar to a matrix https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.broadcasting.html But in the end, they just transform one of the matrices to be the same size as the other

Comment: The author may just have been trying to emphasize the fact that the matrices must be the same size. For the reasons you give, it probably would have been better not to specify "of the same size" in the name of the example, but logically it's just a redundant statement of something you already know.

Answer (score 1):

You can only add matrices of the same dimensions.